# How exactly does open feint and game center multiplayers work?

Tags: iphone, multiplayer, openfeint

I am newbie to this and i can't figure out how they work? Do i have to have own server? How are communications between players done?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question. If you are talking about the Apple's Game Center then I got you an answer.

GameCenter provides an interface that your application needs to follow, so your game can be integrated with the "game social network". You have to own a server only if your game cannot use peer-to-peer connections. The Game Center is very useful because you do not have to implement a lot of resources like matchmaking, achievement-like logistic, leader boards, etc.

You will find more useful information at: [Game Center Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html)

Comment: How can i understand whether my game can use peer-to-peer?

Comment: And if i can't use peer-to-peer and i must have my own app server, how is it integrated with The Game Center? Imagine i have my own app server, all devices connect to a server, but in this case i am not sure how everything is integrated with The Game Center.

Comment: That is not a simple task. You will have to study about iPhone development and take a good read in the Game Center Overview. They got a good explanation out there. About peer-to-peer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer